# Save projects from all collections from Team Foundation Server on disk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have to delete an old Team Foundation server (virtual machine), because the hardware monitor is telling us that disks are about to die. And our team already started using a newer server a long time ago. Therefore all recent projects have been migrated to the new environment, that is for sure. But i also think that  someone has missed some old project and i know for sure that at some point in time mr. Murphy is going to call and asks a question about some very old project :) (which only existed in that very old TFS database.)

So, i was thinking, the best thing to do here, is to get all projects, from all collections, and store them on some archive disk on a NAS. But, what i'm missing is a command or something to do this big 'get everything' task with just a few commands or clicks. Does anyone know how to accomplish this in an easy way?

Comment: Do you want history too?  If not, just right click on `$/` and select "Get Latest Version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should detach all collections and back them up. Once detached you can move them to the new TFS server and "attach" them as additional collections. This will make the contents available for everyone. Set permission to readonly and you can make sure you never miss anything.

Comment: It might need to be upgraded also depending on how "old" they are and if they are on the same version of TFS.  If on 2010 or 2012 you need to use the command line option "tfsconfig import" to "attach" the collection, if on 2013 you can just restore it and attach it from the TFS admin console.